Excel - display formula result, rather than formula
Is there a quick way to stop a formula being displayed to users of a workbook?
There are a number of people using the workbook and multiple VLOOKUP, INDEX MATCH formulas.
I'd like for them to just see the values returned, rather than what's going on behind the scenes to bring them the data.
In particular on one row, where it references notes of a tracker which have multiple lines of text.  If the user double clicks on the cell to see all the notes, the formula appears.

You could protect those formula returned cells or protect whole worksheet if there is no need for any editing of cells in the worksheet.

Unfortunately they need to be able to edit various cells

That is why I have asked you to protect only those cells which have formulas. Probably a faster way of doing this is using VBA but I can't say how to do it. Should be possible with VBA with Worksheet_Change_Event so that whenever you create any new formulas specific cells or ranges will get locked and if you dont want that then once done run a Sub Routine for locking only formulated cells. For VBA you would need to show users what you have tried or may be some kind user will help you out. I am not learned too much in VBA sorry for that!

@user1960205  ,,, it is as simple & just a few click away ,,,, hit the FORMULA on Command menu/Ribbon , then find SHOW FORMULA ,,,, just hit it and U find all FORMULA will disappear and the RESULTS can be seen in place of it !!
